# starting avd fails, saying it can't find emulator, but it exists

Tags: android, ubuntu, emulation, android-virtual-device

I've installed the SDK on Ubuntu 12.0.4.  I started up the SDK manager and updated several packages.

I ran the avd manager and tried to create an avd, but it just failed with no information.

I then tried to create the avd from the command line, using the same information I tried to use from the gui, and it worked.

When I tried to start that AVD, it failed with (some strings elided):

```
Failed to start emulator: Cannot run program "<myhome>/apps/android/android-sdk-linux/tools/emulator": java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
```

This is what I see when I look for this file:

```
$ ls -lt <myhome>/apps/android/android-sdk-linux/tools/emulator
-rwxrwxr-x 1 <me> <me> 24828 May 25 08:20 <myhome>/apps/android/android-sdk-linux/tools/emulator*
```

As you can see, the path it's looking for DOES exist.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Seems like you are running 64 bit system.
So you need to install ia32-libs.

To install ia32-libs, put following line in terminal:

> sudo apt-get install ia32-libs

Answer (score 5):

did the following to resolve this issue:
command-line tool android (android avd), and used Tools->Manage SDK to install 64 bit emulators. I then mv'ed emulator to emulator.old, and emulator64-arm to emulator

with that approach no need to install 32 bit libraries.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using 64-Bit Ubuntu or Linux you just need to rename the emulator to any other name like emulator_backup and emulator64-arm to emulator and this will work.

No need to install 32-bit libraries and also this is a hectic process.

Enjoy Android development on Ubuntu.